# Applying a sparsity pattern to another matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to apply a sparsity pattern to another matrix. At the moment I'm just using assignment after using spalloc. MATLAB alerts that this is slow, but it doesn't give a solution to make it faster. How do I apply the sparsity pattern of A to the matrix FWtrans?

Meaning that the zero values of A have to be zero values in FWtrans. Only indices in A that have a value can have the value of FWtrans in X.

```
Wtrans = transpose(W);
As = sparse(A);
FWtrans = F * Wtrans;
[m,n] = size(FWtrans);
k = find(As);
X = spalloc(m,n, nnz(A));
% Optimize assignment too speed up
for i = k
    X(k) = FWtrans(k);
end
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of allocating the sparse array and then copying values to it, you can use [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to allocate the array and assign the values all at once.

```matlab
Wtrans = transpose(W);
As = sparse(A);
FWtrans = F * Wtrans;
[m,n] = size(FWtrans);

% unfortunately, sparse takes only row/column coordinates...
[r,c] = find(As);
% but it's more convenient to get the values using indices
v = FWtrans(find(As));

% let sparse allocate a m*n array and
% assign the values v to the proper locations
X = sparse(r, c, v, m, n);
```

It might be a bit quicker to use `sub2ind` after `find` in order to find the row/column coordinates instead of calling `find` twice, but I have my doubts.

See also: [Accessing Sparse Matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html#f6-9348)